# Wrong ejs file is being rendered when I go to a particular route, even if its a non-existent route. NodeJs

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, ejs

I am using a button at the end of a survey to run a POST operation. The POST operation for that route does nothing but redirect to the "thank you" page for now. When it routes, a blank survey EJS file is rendered instead of the thank you ejs. This happens even when I have the POST route redirect to a route that hasn't even been defined yet. I could do "res.redirect('survey/ladkjfdalfkj')" instead of the thank you page and a blank survey page is shown.

I've tried replacing the post button with just a link going to the thank you page, still renders the wrong file. I even made the link to a non-existent route and it still renders even though I should get an error since the route doesn't exist.

Here is the app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const chalk = require('chalk');
const debug = require('debug')('app');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');


const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 80;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.use(morgan('tiny'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
//app.use('/css', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css')));
//app.use('/js', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js')));
//app.use('/js', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/jquery/dist')));
app.use('/js', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/js')));
app.use('/css', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/css')));
app.set('views', './src/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

const surveyRouter = require('./src/routes/surveyRoutesTest')();

app.use('/survey', surveyRouter);

app.route('/')
  .get((req, res) => {
    res.send('Access Forbiden')
  });

app.listen(port, () => {
  debug('listening on port ', chalk.green(port));
});
```

Here is the surveyRoutes.js

```
const express = require('express');
const debug = require('debug');
const surveyRouter = express.Router();
const mysql = require('mysql');
var Q = require('q');
require('dotenv').config();

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  host: process.env.DB_HOST
});


connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});


function router() {

  surveyRouter.get('/:surveyGuid/', function(req, res){
    //store parameters
    var surveyGuid = req.params.surveyGuid;
    var prms = req.query;
    var date = prms.s;
    var dmsId = prms.d;

     Q.ninvoke(connection, "query", 'CALL spGetSurveyQuestions(?);', surveyGuid)
      .then(function(rows){
          // console.log(rows[0]);
          questions = rows[0][0];
      })
      .then(function(rows){
        Q.ninvoke(connection, "query", "CALL spGetSurveyQuestionValuesBySurvey(?)", surveyGuid)
        .then(function(rows){
          questionValues = rows[0][0]
          res.render("surveyQuestionsTest", {questions: questions, questionValues:questionValues, surveyGuid: surveyGuid, prms: prms})
        })
      })
      .catch(function(error){
        console.log(error);
        res.writeHead(500);
        res.end();
      })
      .done();
  });


  surveyRouter.post('/:surveyGuid', function(req, res){
    var surveyGuid = req.params.surveyGuid;
    var prms = req.query;
    var date = prms.s;
    var dmsId = prms.d;
    res.redirect("/survey/myself")
  });

  surveyRouter.get('/thankyou', function(req, res){
    res.send("hello world");
  });

  return surveyRouter;
}

module.exports = router;
```

I removed some other routes from this, but they work fine and don't concern the error.

As you can see the thankyou page should only show "Hello world" but its rendering the page at res.render('surveyQuestionsTest)

Here is the surveyQuestionsTest.ejs

```
  <%include partials/header%>

<div id="masthead" class="container">
      <div class="row py-2 shadow">
        <div class="col-md-12 my-3">
          <h1 class=text-center>Dental Patient Satisfaction Survey</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>

<form action="/survey/<%=surveyGuid%>?d=<%=prms.d%>&s=<%=prms.s%>" method="POST">
  <div class="containter">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="mx-5">
          <div id="mainDiv" class="form-group">

            <%questions.forEach(function(question){%>
              <div class="row justify-content-left my-2 border-bottom">
                <label class="question">
                  <strong><span id="questionNumber"><%=question.QustionSequence%>.</span> <%=question.QuestionText%></strong></br>
                </label>
                <!-- DROP DOWN HANDLING -->
                <%if(question.QuestionType == "DropDown"){%>
                  <select  class="form-control my-2 shadow-sm" name="<%=question.QustionSequence%>">
                    <%questionValues.forEach(function(questionValue){%>
                      <%if(questionValue.QuestionId == question.QuestionId){%>
                          <option required value="<%=questionValue.AnswerValue%>,<%= questionValue.AnswerText%>,<%= question.QuestionGuid%>,<%= question.QuestionType%>">
                            <%=questionValue.AnswerText%>
                          </option>
                      <%}%>
                    <%});%> 
                  </select>   
                <%}%>

                <!-- RADIO BUTTON HANDLING -->
                <%if(question.QuestionType == 'RadioButton'){%>
                  <div class="container">
                    <%questionValues.forEach(function(questionValue){%> 
                      <div class="row justify-content-left">
                        <%if(questionValue.QuestionId == question.QuestionId){%>
                            <label class="px-3" >
                              <input class="mx-2" 
                              type="radio" name="<%=question.QustionSequence%>" 
                              value="<%=questionValue.AnswerValue%>,<%= questionValue.AnswerText %>,<%= question.QuestionGuid%>,<%= question.QuestionType%>" 
                              > 
                              <%= questionValue.AnswerText%>
                            </label>
                          </br>
                        <%}%>
                      </div>
                    <%});%>
                  </div>
                <%}%>

                <!-- TEXT BOX HANDLING -->
                <%if(question.QuestionType == 'Text'){%>
                  <div class="container">
                    <%questionValues.forEach(function(questionValue){%> 
                    <%if(questionValue.QuestionId == question.QuestionId){%>
                      <input type="hidden" name="<%=question.QustionSequence%>" value="True,<%= questionValue.AnswerValue %>,<%= question.QuestionType%>,
                      <%= question.QuestionGuid%>">
                      <div class="row justify-content-center shadow-sm">
                        <textarea name="<%=question.QustionSequence%>Text" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>    
                      </div>
                    <%}%>
                  <%});%>
                  </div>
                <%}%>

              </div>
            <%});%>


          </div>
          <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <button id="nextButton" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
            <!-- <a href="/survey/thankyou">Submit</a> -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>


<%include partials/footer%>
```

If I comment out the button and use that Submit link, i still get the same problem. And if that link points to a non-existent route, it still renders a blank surveyQuestionsTest.ejs file rather than showing an error.

I should be getting a thank you page, but I am not.  If I make the /survey/surveyGuid route render the thank you page, the thank you page renders fine.

I think its something in the surveyQuestionsTest.ejs but I'm honestly not sure. I'm quite lost as to what to do. If you need more Info let me know.

Comment: Still no luck in solving this. It's not the post method that's messing up, I think its something in the ejs still.

Answer (score 0):

Very very silly...
the thank you route was interpreted as a /:surveyGuid route...